# Rundeck - Java heap space

Tags: java, rundeck

I have installed Rundeck and added 26 jobs but after some time some of the jobs started failing with error - "Java heap space"

Currently I have this configuration for memory - "-Xmx6144m -Xms6144m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" but it`s not enough. Is it expected that Rundeck consumes a lot of memory or maybe I configured Rundeck in the wrong way. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `RDECK_JVM= -Xmx` from 1024m to maximum size of the instance in `/etc/rundeck/profile`